# Is possible to get dependency/pos information for entities in Spacy?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, dependency-parsing

I am working on extracting entities from scientific text (I am using **scispacy**) and later I will want to extract relations using hand-written rules. I have extracted entities and their character span successfully, and I can also get the pos and dependency tags for tokens and noun chunks. So I am comfortable with the two tasks separately, but I want to bring the two together and I have been stuck for a while.

The idea is that I want to be able to write rules such as: (just an example) if in a sentence/clause there are two entities where the first one is a 'DRUG/CHEMICAL' + is the *subject*, and the second one is a 'DISEASE' + is an *object* --> (then) infer 'treatment' relation between the two.

If anyone has any hints on how to approach this task, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

S.

What I am doing to **extract entities**:

`doc = nlp(text-with-more-than-one-sent)`

`for ent in doc.ents:`

```
`... (get information about the ent e.g. its character span)`
```

**Getting dependency information (for noun chunks and for tokens):**

`for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:`

`print(f"Text: {chunk.text}, Root text: {chunk.root.text}, Root dep: {chunk.root.dep_}, Root head text: {chunk.root.head.text}, POS: {chunk.root.head.pos_}")`

_

`for token in doc:`

`print(f"Text: {token.text}, DEP label: {token.dep_}, Head text: {token.head.text}, Head POS: {token.head.pos_}, Children: {[child for child in token.children]}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`merge_entities`](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities) mini-component to convert entities to single tokens, which would simplify what you're trying to do. There's also a component to merge noun chunks similarly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've been playing around with merge_entities and it definitely makes the task I'm trying to achieve much easier :)

Comment: Glad it helps. Note you can accept my answer by clicking the large checkmark to the left of it.